# How can I change a custom variable in JSX to be passed to a CSS var()?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'd like to edit the `cat-color` variable in `filter_category` depending on a condition. Here is a minimal working example of the CSS file

```css
:root {
  --cat-color: red;
}

.categories_filter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;

  .filter_category {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--cat-color);
  }
}
```

And here is a minimal working example of JSX which includes the css style that I want to change its property in a custom way.

```
return (
  <Layout {...this.props}>
    <div className="inner">
      <ul className="categories_filter">
        {newCats.map((category, id) => (
          <li
            key={id}
            className={`${
              category === activeCategory && "activeCat"
            } filter_category`}
            onClick={() => this.handleFilter(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will help you - 
https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript

```
document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--my-variable-name', 'pink');
```

Comment: This is good, but I need something similar for JSX so that I can edit the property inside the `className` depending on the condition that I set

Comment: If you want this to be handled by classname only, you can do so by adding another class with different color. Ex. 

`.filter_category { .filter_category_disabled { color: red } }`

Answer (score 0):

Basicslly the way this is done in react is changing the class that it has, not the class itself. You could go for something like this:

```
return (
  <Layout {...this.props}>
    <div className="inner">
      <ul className="categories_filter">
        {newCats.map((category, id) => (
          <li
            key={id}
 V          className={`${
             ( category === activeCategory) ? "activeCat" : 
               "filter_category"}`}
            onClick={() => this.handleFilter(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what have been changed, and how can that change `cat-color` ?